# Reformatting column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting, powerbi-desktop

I am migrating a dashboard from **Tableau** to **Power BI**. I have a **(Y/N)** column for personal information as shown in the picture below:

[image: Here]

Is it possible to format that column, so it looks something similar to this in **Power BI**?:

[image: Here]

Update Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, pretty easy

```
Measure = 
VAR _1 =
MAX ( 'fact'[personalInfo] )
VAR _2 =
SWITCH ( TRUE (), _1 = BLANK (), "", _1 = "Y", "", "" )
RETURN
_2
```

[image: Solution]

More granular level

```
Measure2 = 
VAR _1 =
    MAX ( 'fact'[personalInfo] )
VAR _blue = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
                <svg xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" width='100 px' height='100px' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>                  
                         <rect width=""30"" height=""30"" x=""35"" y=""35"" style=""fill:#4E79A7"" />
            </svg>" 
VAR _orange = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
                <svg xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" width='100 px' height='100px' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>                  
                         <rect width=""30"" height=""30"" x=""35"" y=""35"" style=""fill:#F28E2B"" />
            </svg>" 
VAR _red = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
                <svg xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" width='100 px' height='100px' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>                  
                         <rect width=""30"" height=""30"" x=""35"" y=""35"" style=""fill:#E15759"" />
            </svg>" 
VAR _2 =
    SWITCH ( TRUE (), _1 = BLANK (), _blue ,_1 = "Y", _orange, _red)
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! I tried using the code you wrote but its creating a column called 'measure' instead for some reason. Please see the updated picture.

Comment: try using a matrix viz, I have updated my screenshot for your ease of understanding.